# Laravel and Pusher

Tags: laravel, pusher

I am working on a real-time chat application between backend(Laravel 5.5) and mobile application. I am using pusher-js for front-end and vinkla/pusher for the server which is working perfectly fine.
Now when the application is killed or in the background, I need to integrate push notification, not real-time messaging. I am planning to use this package "https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/pusher-push-notifications", but when i try to install this via composer, i get this error all the time:

[Installation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wuZE.png)

Comment: run composer update in the console.. and see if it updates your packages

Comment: i am not even able to install it, vinkla/pusher had been installed already

Comment: what I mean was... before installing anything run "composer update".. then install.. now you have to try it on another project since you have already installed some package or install it first and run  "composer update" and then install push notifications package

Comment: on this project i have tried solution but still no luck, lets see if i can install it on new a new project.

Comment: Can you show us your composer.json file?

Comment: composer.json: 

"require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "laravel-notification-channels/pusher-push-notifications": "^1.0",
        "vinkla/pusher": "^3.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    },